# String inside an excel vba formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that insert the formula below in a cell.
I want to combine A7 and string "EBF" into one string inside the VLOOKUP formula but it seems to keep giving me error.

This is what I want in the excel cell:

=D7-IFERROR (VLOOKUP (A7&"CAF",sheet1!A1:B31,2,FALSE),0)

This is my VBA Code to insert the formula into the cell:

```
Range("H7") = "=D7-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A7 & ""EBF"" & ",sheet1!A2:B31,2,FALSE),0)"
```

Comment: Why do you have an extra `& "` after `""EBF""`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like (Remembering to use the .Formula to assign)

```
Range("H7").Formula = "=D7-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A7 & ""CAF"" ,sheet1!A2:B31,2,FALSE),0)"
```

Comment: And decide if it is CAF or EBF

Answer (score 0):

`"=D7-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A7&""EBF"",sheet1!A2:B31,2,FALSE),0)"`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.